# Multiple notification in android for same app not working?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I have implemented push notifications for my android app .I am able to show multiple notification in notification bar but only one notification work at a time.If I click on any notification it will start the intended activity and that particular notification will disappear from notification bar but other notification for same app will become dead.Nothing happens when I click on rest of the notification.My code for handling notification is following:

```
private void sendNotification(String msg, String msgId, int notificationId,
            int type) {
        // SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(
        // Utility.PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Intent intent = null;
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        if (type == 1) {
            intent = new Intent(this, Activity_Received.class);

            // bundle.putString("greeting", msg);
            bundle.putString(Utility.KEY_MESSAGE_DELIVERY_ID, msgId);

        } else if (type == 2) {
            intent = new Intent(this, Activity_Birth.class);

        } else {
            return;
        }

        bundle.putBoolean(Utility.KEY_IS_NOTIFICATION, true);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);

        PendingIntent contentIntent;

        // The stack builder object will contain an artificial back stack
        // for
        // the
        // started Activity.
        // This ensures that navigating backward from the Activity leads out
        // of
        // your application to the Home screen.
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        // Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)

        if (type == 1) {
            stackBuilder.addParentStack(Activity_Received.class);
        } else {
            stackBuilder.addParentStack(Activity_Birth.class);
        }
        // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);

        contentIntent = stackBuilder
                .getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                        | PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("WishnGreet")
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
                .setContentText(msg)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(
                        RingtoneManager
                                .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));


        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(notificationId, mBuilder.build());
    }
```

Please advise what do I need to change in above code so that I can click on every notification that I receive for my application and start the intended activity.

Comment: pass this as a notificationId :  int requestID = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have wrote the following method which is working in case of multiple notifications.

```
private void pushNotification(String msg, String msgId, int notificationId,
            int type) {
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(Utility.KEY_MESSAGE_DELIVERY_ID, msgId);
        bundle.putBoolean(Utility.KEY_IS_NOTIFICATION, true);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity_ReceivedGreeting.class);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                getApplicationContext(), notificationId, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("WishnGreet")
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
                .setContentText(msg)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(
                        RingtoneManager
                                .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(notificationId, mBuilder.build());
    }
```

The key was to remove the FLAGS on pending intent.

Answer (score 4):

Pass a different notificationId for each different notification you want to have in the method: `sendNotification(String msg, String msgId, int notificationId, int type)`

Comment: notificationId is always different in my case, still I am facing this problem.

Comment: Also check the `type` variable passed to this method is always either 1 or 2

Comment: Stepping into the code of this method to check the values of the variables should help